# Calling a callable object by std::thread with std::function as a parameter

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create an async call to a member function that gets as an std::function type parameter. However, I got the following error:

```
Error   C2672   'std::invoke': no matching overloaded function found
Error   C2893   Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...) noexcept(<expr>)'
```

The code looks like this

```
void clientMessageHandler(MyBaseObject * objectBase, char * buffer, size_t size)
{

}

   void MyObject::dispatcher(std::function<void(MyBaseObject *, char *, size_t)> pfnMessageHandler)
        {
        }

void MyObject::recv(std::function<void(MyBaseObject *, char *, size_t)> pfnMessageHandler)
{
    m_dispatchThread = std::thread(&MyObject::dispatcher, pfnMessageHandler);
}
```

main:

```
MyObject object;
object.recv(clientMessageHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

Is `MyObject::dispatcher` a `static` member function? Otherwise you need to provide an object to call it on with the `std::thread`:

```
m_dispatchThread = std::thread(&MyObject::dispatcher, this, pfnMessageHandler);
//                                                    ^^^^
//               The object to call the member function on
```

Comment: it worked. thanks. But, MyObject::dispatcher is not a static member function, it's a private. why the compiler does not pass "this" automatically? is private member function is necessarily a static? i'm confused.

Comment: How can it know on which object you want to execute the method? C++ is about being explicit.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher got it : )